# Dark Grey Background Color in ZSH using Autoload

Tags: shell, colors, zsh, prompt

I would like to create a dark grey background for my prompt in ZSH and am not using 256-color mode.  I'm loading the colors with autoload and cannot get it to show any greys besides a single foreground grey.

I've tried every combination of greys that I could think of.

```
autoload colors && colors

PS1="%{$bg_no_bold[grey]%}%{$fg_no_bold[grey]%} NoBold %{$bg_bold[grey]%}%{$fg_bold[grey]%} Bold %{$bg[grey]%}%{$fg[grey]%} Normal"
```

I would expect the code below to show basically show two or three shades of grey, the words would obviously be unreadable because the foreground and the background are the same colors, but all I get as results are two dark grey words (no background colors at all): "Bold Nothing"

Comment: Is your terminal *capable* of displaying the different colors?

Comment: Good question, chepner.  Yes it was, it seems like autoload does not have an associated color name for the dark grey I was looking for.  I posted a solution to my question that works, though I don't know why this darker version of the grey seems to not be included in the autoload, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to set black as black, white as bold white, bold grey as non-bold white and non-bold grey I needed to specify the ANSI value for:

```
BlackFG="%{$fg[black]%}"
WhiteFG="%{$fg_bold[white]%}"
BoldGreyFG="%{$fg_no_bold[white]%}"
NonBoldGreyFG="%F{8}"
```

It seems like what I call non-bold grey is not included in the auto-load colors, though it would be nice for someone to chime in if they have any idea why this dark grey color appears to be missing.